# Javascript Typerror variable undefined.

Tags: javascript, json

I m trying to make a simple dumb tic-tac-toe game using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

In the below function for the player move the ComputerMove Function cannot be called because of Typeerror in JSON object.

```
function Mymove(idValue) 
{
 var flag=0;
 var image = document.getElementById(idValue);
 if (image.src.match("blank.png")) {
 image.src = "X.png";
 flag=Check();
 if (flag==1) 
  {
  alert("You Won");
  reset();
  return;
  };
 ComputerMove();
 };
} 
function Check(){
   for (var i =0 ; i <= 8;i++) {
   var image=document.getElementById(winList[i].a);
   if (!image.src.match("blank.png")) {
   if(image.src==document.getElementById(winList[i].b).src && image.src==document.getElementById(winList[i].c).src)
   return 1;
 }
 }
```

Here is the JSON object below:-

```
var winList =[
    {a:1,b:2,c:3},
    {a:4,b:5,c:6},
    {a:7,b:8,c:9},
    {a:1,b:4,c:7},
    {a:2,b:5,c:8},
    {a:3,b:6,c:9},
    {a:1,b:5,c:9},
    {a:3,b:5,c:7}];
```

The check function works always, and the console response as

```
TypeError: winList[i] is undefined
```

While Debugging I found after this error the ComputerMove() function never gets called.
So please help.

Comment: If the `flag` is `1`, the `ComputeMove()` doesn't get executed. Is this fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `winList` array has a length of 8, with an index spanning from 0 - 7.

Your loop `for (var i =0 ; i <= 8;i++)` tries to access the `winList[8]` (when the `i == 8`), which is `undefined` - thus crashing the script when you try to access `a` of `undefined` (`winList[i].a`).

Try changing your loop condition to the following: `for (var i = 0 ; i < 8; i++)`

Comment: it needs 3 more minutes.. I will be doing it, sooner. :)