# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object when trying to generate a table dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to render a table dynamically based on the data that it gets. That part works, however the moment I implemented a filtered version of the data I get the TypeError Undefined or Null to object error on the `let headings = Object.key(data[1])` line.

```
import React from "react";
import tableData from "./tableData1.js";

const TableComponent = ({ data }) => {
**let headings = Object.keys(data[1]);** //This is where I get the Error
  return (
    <table className="table table-dark table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="16">Dimensions in mm</th>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="col">
          <th>Series</th>
          {headings.map((heading) => (
            <th>{heading}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <tr scope="col">
            <th scope="row">Series No.</th>
            {headings.map((heading) => (
              <td>{item[heading]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const TableGenerator = () => {
  const filteredData = tableData.filter(item => item.id == 1).map(item => item.value);
  return <TableComponent data={filteredData} />;
};

export default TableGenerator;
```

Here is the Data for reference(currently just some mock data):

```
const tableData1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: {
      A: "Value",
      B: "Value",
      C: "Value",
      D: "Male",
      E: "Value",
      G: "Value",
      H: "Value",
      I: "Value",
      L: "Value",
      M: "Value",
      N: "Value",
      P: "Value",
      Q: "Value",
      R: "Value",
      S: "Value",
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: {
      A: "Value",
      B: "Value",
      C: "Value",
      D: "Male",
      E: "Value",
      G: "Value",
      H: "Value",
      I: "Value",
      L: "Value",
      M: "Value",
      N: "Value",
      P: "Value",
      Q: "Value",
      R: "Value",
      S: "Value",
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: {
      A: "Value",
      B: "Value",
      C: "Value",
      D: "Male",
      E: "Value",
      G: "Value",
      H: "Value",
      I: "Value",
      L: "Value",
      M: "Value",
      N: "Value",
      P: "Value",
      Q: "Value",
      R: "Value",
      S: "Value",
    }
  },
];

export default tableData1;
```

It was working before I had added the `const filteredData` section and I was passing in tableData straight to `TableComponent` and I can't figure out why. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: You filter is returning an array with a single element - yet your are attempting to access the second element with `Object.keys(data[1])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting an error Typerror Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64608116) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25823269/10952503) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27509/10952503)

Comment: @Elikill58 - that is not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn silly mistake, you are right, that was the issue. Thank you for pointing that out, I kept going in circles looking at everything else but that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `data[1];` is returning undefined and therefore can't be used by `Object.keys()`.

This probably means your filteredData is being filtered wrong or you are accessing it at the wrong index.